# How to pass the dynamic column names in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
--Drop the table if exists
 drop proc if exists test_sp

 use testdb
 go

 create procedure test_sp
     (@metric varchar(50)  = NULL,
      @from_date date = NULL,
      @to_date date = NULL)
 as 
 begin
    set nocount on;

    --declaring the column name type
    declare @column_name decimal(25,2)

    --specifying the column name based on the metric provided
    if @metric = 'Sales'
    begin
        @column_name = 'sales_value'
    end
    else
    begin
        @column_name = 'revenue_value'
    end

    --sum the value based on the metric
    select sum(@column_name) 
    from <dataset>  
    where metric = @metric 
end

-- execute the procedure
exec test_sp @metric = 'sales'
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time, and maybe others will with, with understanding your question. As it's currently written, it is difficult to piece together what your problem is. Can you try rewriting this for better clarity into your problem?

Comment: you should add some more context to your question as @Jouster500 has suggested. Currently, the one line sentence for the title *could* leave some assumptions open.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to dynamic sql you can use a case expression. This will make the entirety of your procedure this simple.

```
create procedure test_sp
(
    @metric varchar(50)  = NULL
    ,@from_date date =NULL
    ,@to_date date =Null
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select sum(case when @metric = 'Sales' then sales_value else revenue_value end) from <dataset>  where metric = @metric 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic SQL here. You can't use a variable for an object (table name, column name, etc) without it.

```
...

   declare @sql varchar(max)

   --sum the value based on the metric

   set @sql = 'select sum(' + @column_name + ') from <dataset>  where metric = ' + @metric 
   print(@sql) --this is what will be executed in when you uncomment the command below
   --exec (@sql)
end

--execute the procedure
 exec test_sp @metric ='sales'
```

But, you could eliminate it all together... and shorten your steps

```
 use testdb
 go
 create procedure test_sp
     (
     @metric varchar(50)  = NULL
     ,@from_date date =NULL
     ,@to_date date =Null
     )
 AS
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

--specifying the column name based on the metric provided
 if @metric = 'Sales'
 begin
    select sum('sales_value') 
    from yourTable 
    where metric = @metric --is this really needed?
 end
else 
 begin
    select sum('revenue_value') 
    from yourTable 
    where metric = @metric  --is this really needed?
 end
```

Also, not sure what `@from_date` and `@to_date` are for since you don't use them in your procedure. I imagine they are going in the `WHERE` clause eventually.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Is it not possible in the format which i have quoted the question?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but i added anther solution @Athiq

Comment: Thanks @scsimon :) . I am currently using the same way as you mentioned in the another method(not dynamic sql). And yes the from_date and to_date are used in the where clause. And also metric is needed.But i was looking to shorten the length of the code by using something like dynamic sql

Comment: so this answer should suffice then @Athiq, great!

Comment: But i believe we dont have similar method like dynamic sql which will help to shorten the code ?